# SharePoint 2010 - Search configurations

Tags: search, sharepoint

How to remove the lists and items should not be appear in the search results page.

Example allpages.aspx should not appear in the index/search results page.

Thanks,
Umesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Lists Settings in web browser. Then chose Advanced Settings and in Search section select answer for "Allow items from this list to appear in search results?"

Comment: This option will appear or not in the search results.